# chromium-browser unexpectedly quit (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: python, google-chrome, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to get Chromedriver to work with Ubuntu.  I'm running Ubuntu on AWS (EC2).  I checked `/usr/bin` and I see that the following packages are in there:

```
chromedriver               
chromium-browser
```

So, my code is as follows:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromium-browser', chrome_options=options)
```

And, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 40, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromium-browser', chrome_options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromium-browser unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

If I check my current Chrome browser version, I see I'm using version 78.0.3904.70.  Is it possible the drivers I'm using are out of date?

I'm also wondering: what is the difference between chromium-browser, and Chromedriver?  I've used Chromedriver in the past to log onto Chrome to use with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set executable path to `chromedriver` because that is what `selenium` uses. So that line of code needs to be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Thank you - I new get a new error; WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable.  Does this mean I need to downgrade chrome version?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to add this option: `chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')`

Comment: This is already in my code:  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox').  See my original code..

Comment: Sorry, i missed it. I think problem is incompatible versions of chromedriver, and Selenium.

Comment: How might I fix this?!

Comment: Try to update chromedriver and selenium to latest version. I can not think of anything else.

Comment: I literally installed selenium a few days ago.  Wouldn't it be up - to -date?  Is there a way to check whether it's updated?

Comment: I am using selenium  with 3.141.0 and ChromeDriver with 78.0.3904.11 versions and they work just fine. You can check version typing `pip show selenium`.

Comment: Thanks Marceline.  So, I realized maybe selenium was not properly installed.  So, I did pip3 install selenium, with the result: Installing collected packages: urllib3, selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0 urllib3-1.25.6

Comment: The issue now is I get this warning: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.6) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
I'm guessing maybe I need to downgrade urllib.....

Comment: How do I tell what version of selenium I'm using?  As well as version of chromedriver?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201478/discussion-between-marceline-and-diamondjoe12).